# Schedule a job on SQL Server 2014 without an AGENT

Tags: sql-server-2014

How to schedule a SQL Server 2014 job without the Agent or T-SQL ? Is it possible using stored procedures? I need to schedule a weekly job on SQL Server 2014. I know how to do it using a batch file in Windows, if there are any other ways please let me know. Thanks in advance !

Comment: SQL Server Agent is the subsystem that's there to handle jobs - if you don't have the SQL Server Agent - you **cannot** schedule jobs in SQL Server

Comment: @marc_s not strictly true. For example, if you're using SQL Server on Linux you could set up scripts using `crontab`. On Windows you could use Task Scheduler. **Why** you'd use those instead of Agent is a completely different question, however. To the OP, however, you certainly, wouldn't be able to do it without using SQL Server Agent **and** without using T-SQL.

Comment: @Larnu: but SQL Server **2014** isn't available on Linux - right? Only 2016 and 2017 ...

Comment: @marc_s c3027 only. Why I mentioned task scheduler. :)

Comment: @Larnu If I have 2016 I could have used autosys to schedule the box jobs in Unix but thats not an option. So, my only option would be T-SQL since my organization does not have SQL server Agent. Your inputs on how to go about using T-SQL is appreciated. please share any source code if available once again thanks in advance.

Comment: Just noticed I completely typoed that comment. Should have said 2017 only.

Comment: Is there any reason you don't have agent? It comes, as standard, with Standard edition. Are you using web or express?

Comment: I have no clue as to why they don't have the agent.... they want me to use Visual Studio to create SSIS packages and run them through Visual studio. Here is the Edition and version of my SQL. 12.0.5207.0 SP2 Enterprise Edition (64-bit) v4.0.30319 SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL 1033 POKCDSQLMK02

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but I'm looking for something similar, and recently came across a solution that discusses using the [SQL Server Service Broker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms166043(v=sql.90)) to accomplish this.
These two posts from SQLTeam -- [Scheduling Jobs in SQL Server Express](https://www.sqlteam.com/articles/scheduling-jobs-in-sql-server-express) and [Scheduling Jobs in SQL Server Express - Part 2](https://www.sqlteam.com/articles/scheduling-jobs-in-sql-server-express-2) -- are written with SQL Server 2005 Express in mind, and they discuss how to use [BEGIN CONVERSATION TIMER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/begin-conversation-timer-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to set up scheduled tasks without using a SQL Server Agent.

That all being said, in this particular case, another couple of options come to mind:

1. If you know how to do it using batch files in windows, then you could consider just using the Windows Task Scheduler with [SQLCMD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility).
2. Based on your comment that they have  SQL [...] Enterprise Edition (64-bit), I believe that they **do** have SQL Server Agent, and they just need to add your account to the SQLAgentUserRole.